# how to save r dataframe as an image

Tags: r, gridextra

How can I create an image  from a data frame?  For example:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(gridExtra)
 df = iris %>% slice(1:4)
```

I've the following but:
1.  I haven't been able to get this to be saved to a variable.  It just pops up in the plots pane of Rstudio.  Am I missing something obvious?  I'd like to be able to have this plot referenced to a variable so I could save it as a png or something.
2. Is there a way to remove the row numbers that seem to appear?
3. This look is fine, but is there a way to make it more of a lighter background compared to what this is?

```
gridExtra::grid.table(df)
```

Comment: Have you looked at `knitr::kable` and `kableExtra::kable_as_image`?  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/54026046/2554330 for a complicated example.

Answer (score 3):

1. To save a relevant variable, use

```
myTable <- tableGrob(df)
```

since

```
grid.table
# function (...) 
# grid.draw(tableGrob(...))
# <bytecode: 0x10758c078>
# <environment: namespace:gridExtra>
```

Given that, you can run

```
library(grid)
grid.draw(myTable)
```

2. For that you want

```
myTable <- tableGrob(df, rows = NULL)
```

3. See `?tableGrob` and particularly `ttheme_default` (its source code makes pretty clear what are possible parameters; see also [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gridExtra/vignettes/tableGrob.html)). For instance,

```
myTable <- tableGrob(
  df, 
  rows = NULL, 
  theme = ttheme_default(core = list(bg_params = list(fill = "grey99")))
)
grid.draw(myTable)
```

[image]